# When I share post viva whatsapp share button in codeigniter postted image not showing like thumlin and we image fetch form database

Tags: codeigniter

When I share post viva whatsapp share button in codeigniter postted image not showing like thumlin and we image fetch form database
and also I see view source to image name showing proparlly

View Source

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="htttp://statenews.co.in/images/product_images/1000raj.jpg" />
```

View

**Head Meta tag**

```
<meta name="description" content="The Fatest News Channel">
<meta property="og:title" content="StateNews ! Hosla Sach Karne Ka..">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="News">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />

<?php $file=base_url()."homeassets/images/".$product_images->image; 
if(file_exists($file)){
?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/product_images/<?php echo $product_images->image; ?>" />
<?php
}else{
?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/product_images/<?php echo $product_images->image; ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
```

**Whatsapp Button**

```
<li style="background: #71b733;">
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo base_url() . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-link="<?php echo base_url() . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" target="_blank" style="color:inherit;">
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
</a>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
$data['products'] = $this->User_model->get_all_data_by2('products','product_images','product_id','master','Common',base_url(),'added_at','DESC',10);




$this->load->view('include/header',$data);
$this->load->view('home',$data);
$this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
```

**Model**

```
function get_all_data_by2($table1='',$table2='',$colum1='',$colum='',$value='',$value2='',$color='',$ord='',$limit=''){
if((!empty($value)) && (!empty($colum))) { 
$this->db->where($colum, $value);
}
if(!empty($value2)){
$this->db->or_where($colum, $value2);
}
if((!empty($ord)) && (!empty($color))){
$this->db->order_by($color,$ord);
}
if(!empty($limit)){
$this->db->limit($limit);
}
$query = $this->db->select('*')
->from($table1)
->join($table2, "$table2.$colum1 = $table1.$colum1")
->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: can you please revise your problem statement and format your code. it is hard to understand the problem and the code is unreadable in its current state.

Comment: when i click whatsap share button go to whatsapp login page then share my post , now hare all detail include but image not visible like preview image get by data base and i can see page view source i get the image name  you can try to  hare -> statenews.co.in

Comment: ???????????????